# Laravel Integrate Google Cloud Storage

Tags: laravel-5, google-cloud-storage

Im trying to integrate Google Cloud Storage for file uploads and serving in a laravel app that is stored in Google Compute Engine.

What would be the best practice for that?
Is it the right way of using the Google Cloud Storage?

Should I use the Storage facade for that? or a Job for copying local file uploads to the cloud?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) to send requests to the Google Cloud Storage JSON API. Visit this [link for example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples).

Answer (score 1):

Better approach is to **directly uploading** to cloud storage.

As directly uploading needs to upload *file data* only once in other process you will have to first upload it to *some temp file* and then from that *temp file to cloud storage*. So as data transfer is more it would be slower and image can be unavailable also till the time job runs and move it from temp location to cloud storage.

> Now let's address **how to upload directly in *cloud storage* using
>   Laravel**. Below steps can be followed to achieve it :-

1. Import CloudStorageTools
   `use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;`
2. Create bucket url to directly uploading file
   `$bucket_options = ['gs_bucket_name' => $my_bucket];
   $cloud_storage_upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload/handler', $bucket_options);`
3. Now above generated `$cloud_storage_upload_url` can be used in `action` tag of form to upload file directly.
   **Example:-**
   `<form action="{{ upload_url }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">`

**Footnote :-** Upload url we generated would be only accessible till **10 minutes** of it's creation.

Also documentation for same can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload#createuploadurl_options).