# How to upload an image or file to a Cloud Storage using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, firebase, google-cloud-storage

So, I build an API, but the files and images are saved into my local cpanel directory, so that anyone who's trying to receive a data such as files and images cannot retrieve it since the value on database is only a path to my local directory.

By that, I would like to change the directory of the uploaded images or files to Cloud Storage such as Firebase or Dropbox. And I want to save the URL of the files that I just uploaded into the database. Can anyone tell me how to do it step by step? Thank you..

Comment: have you checked https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem ?

Comment: @ml59 I'm sorry, but I still don't know how to implement it

Comment: 1-choose a driver to use (S3, FTP etc). 2- check the doc to work with the dirver (S3 need to install a package etc) 3- add the needed conf in you filesystem.php file (credential etc). 4- use the Storage facade to store/get a file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Integrate Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122634/laravel-integrate-google-cloud-storage)

Comment: @OsvaldoLópez Thank you, I'm sure that this is the correct way

Comment: On Laravel I'd use: https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cloud-storage.html